# Find northbridge of my motherboard

Tags: motherboard, overheating, northbridge

So according to his question I have a heating problem with my 6 years old motherboard. I presume its due to thermal paste beeing wasted. How can I find wich part of my motherboard is the northbridge...
This is my model: ga-a75m-d2h

[image]

Comment: i didn't see any image !! and (his question)??!  you are talking about who ?

Comment: see now. There was a problem with the image server

Answer (score 3):

A [northbridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)) is a component of the motherboard chipset that goes between the CPU and the memory. Your motherboard doesn't have a northbridge. The memory controller is on the CPU die.

Have a look at a typical FM1 socket system block diagram below -- notice there is no northbridge and the memory (on the top right) is connected directly to the CPU (the block labeled "AMD FM1 APU").

[image: FM1 system block diagram]

Comment: Wouldn't you change the thermal paste?

Comment: Probably not since it's very unlikely to be a problem. But having no idea what your issue is, it's hard for me to form a useful opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, **your motherboard does not have a northbridge**.  However it does have a "Fusion Controller Hub" chip which is the chip under the heatsink on the lower left hand corner of the picture.

Chips like this get very hot (by design).

I can say I usually try and find a way to get a fan on any heatsinks like these for my main use desktops. I measure the fins and figure out which size, usually 40-50mm, will line up with the fins. Getting a screw to fit into shallow fins can be tricky, but realistically just about any forced air movement will be a great improvement over natural convection so you just have to get it to stay in place at all.

This of course would not solve old crusty thermal paste, but could prolong the life of the chip, thermal paste, etc. Ebay is a easy place to get these.

Comment: Wouldn't you change the thermal paste?

Comment: @Zaico I have not taken off factory installed heatsinks because I have never had an above design high of a temperature to mitigate so I've added fans really as a preventative measure.  When I change hardware I scalp the installed fans and reuse them and I have backups on hand of 40, 80, and 120mm fans ready for them to fail; although I do buy cheap fans usually around $1-$3 ea.  I just have a habit that is simple and inexpensive and seems to keep my component failures to near zero.

Comment: @Zaico Just a reminder, your question is about "where is your northbridge".  The answer(s) posted are in reference to that.